# I want to check if my Unknown lvl 2 frame is fake

Tags: frames

The main color of the frame is maroon, the logo is black, but, it's stickered on, and the seller said, since its a lvl 2 frame, its supposed to be stickered on.
So now I don't know if its true or not.

Comment: Can you please add photos of the whole bike and the logo sticker as a separate picture?

Comment: It seems the best way to determine if stickers are on a legitimate Unknown lvl 2 frame would be to ask the maker. I looked all over [Unknown Bicycles](https://www.unknownbikes.com) for a customer service or contact link or page and didn't find it. Maybe it will appear after you create an account and log in.

Comment: Please add photos, especially of any and all identifying markings.  Currently you have not given us enough to even start.